# Which Ubuntu-based distributions have stripped out snap?

Tags: snap

Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383583/is-it-true-that-snap-has-proprietary-server) and comments I would like to know which Ubuntu-based distributions have stripped out all snap bits? I love Ubuntu's LTS stability but snaps are not suitable for me for a number of reasons.

Edit: I'm asking about official distributions.

Comment: If this question is about anything other than the official Ubuntu flavours, I'd say it's offtopic here.

Comment: I'm using UbuntuStudio 21.10 which has snapd installed by default, but in a fresh installation there is not a single snap installed, so you could simply run `apt purge snapd`. I'm not a great friend with snaps too, but it's nice to have the option to use a snap when needed...

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *All on-topic flavors of Ubuntu include snap infrastructure; but a number of them come with no snaps installed; eg. Lubuntu for one*

Comment: I have edited question to make it clear I am asking about official distributions.

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "stripped"? In all official flavours, I'd say installing Chromium, for example, would install the snap, since the apt package iirc is just a placeholder for the snap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All [official](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) Ubuntu flavours are:

- **Kubuntu**, 16.04+ [snap preinstalled](https://snapcraft.io/install/snap-store/kubuntu) by default
- **Lubuntu**, 18.10+ [snap preinstalled](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-lubuntu) by default
- **Ubuntu Kylin**, no info, but I assume it is preinstalled by default.
- **Ubuntu MATE**, snap preinstalled by default (thanks to @Andra from the comments)
- **Ubuntu Studio**, no snap packages, but snap is preinstalled, (thanks to @mook765)
- **Xubuntu**, 16.04+ [snap preinstalled](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-xubuntu) by default

Other non-official Ubuntu flavours like **Linux Mint, Pop!_OS, GalliumOS** does not have snap preinstalled.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3 - snap preinstalled by default, snaps=software-boutique, ubuntu-mate-welcome, core18

Comment: All *flavors* have snap infrastructure installed; Ubuntu Studio was already mentioned in comments as coming with no *snap* packages; Ubuntu-MATE comes with snap packages as the Welcome app for example has been packaged as a *snap* for a number of releases now & all supported release (software-boutique is snap too)

Answer (score 5):

#### Removing `snap`.

As [mook765](https://askubuntu.com/users/590937/mook765) [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383587/which-ubuntu-based-distributions-have-stripped-out-snap#comment2386068_1383587), you can `remove` or `purge` `snap`.

if you don't want to use `snap`, [simply `purge` it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/1460940)  by running:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

#### What you asked:

Is there any official flavour of Ubuntu that does not include `snap` by default?

As, [Olimjon](https://askubuntu.com/users/486734/olimjo) said in their [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1383599/1460940), every official flavour of Ubuntu has `snapd` installed by default. Other distributions, which are based on Ubuntu eg: Pop OS!, Mint, etc., don't have snap installed by default. If you want to stick with Ubuntu and official flavours, then I recommend to `purge` `snapd`.